# convert dateTime string to dateTime

Tags: date, datetime, xquery, oracle-service-bus

the source for my integration is sending the date time as `07/01/2015 23:59:00 UTC` and expects the output to be `2015-07-01T23:59:00-00:00`.

in Oracle Service Bus, i used the functions   `fn-bea:dateTime-from-string-with-format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z,data($products/startDate))` the output is 2015-07-01T23:59:00Z.

Is there a inbuilt function to get the above time pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Use `format-dateTime($dateTime, $pattern)` with a matching date picture string. For example:

```
format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01][Z]")
```

Output (for my current time and timezone):

```
2015-06-30T23:45:51+02:00
```